# real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=2x$. Can you think of functions $g$ and $h$ which satisfy the two equations:

1. $ g\circ f=2gh $
2. $ h\circ f=h^2-g^2 $

Which are such functions $g$ and $h$ satisfying these conditions how to find them?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How is it now jose?

Comment: It's much better, but what does $•$ mean? Did you mean to write $\circ$?

Comment: Oh yes composite functions

Comment: Did you already learn about trigonometric functions and theorems?

Comment: Yeah long before...

Comment: You could also experiment with the fact that $(h+ig)(2x)=((h+ig)(x))^2$ to conclude something like $(h+ig)(x)=(a+ib)^x$ as a more general possibility..

Comment: If you allow g=h then try g=h=0.

Answer (score 2):

The functions $g(x)=\sin(x)\text{ and } h(x)=\cos(x)$ satisfy the conditions. Since,
$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$$

If you can recall these trig identities, then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, we replace $x$ by $2^t$ and directly express $g,h$ as functions of $t$.

From

$$G(t+1)=2G(t)H(t),\\H(t+1)=H^2(t)-G^2(t).$$
you draw
$$G^2(t+1)+H^2(t+1)=(H^2(t)+G^2(t))^2, $$ which is of the form

$$I(t+1)=I^2(t),$$ and by induction

$$I(t+k)=I^{2^k}(t).$$

Then for an abritrary function $\iota(t)$ defined on $[0,1)$,

$$I(t)=\iota^{2^{\lfloor t\rfloor}}\left(\{ t\}\right),$$ where ${\lfloor t\rfloor}$ is the fractional part of $t$.

Next,

$$\arctan\frac{G(t+1)}{H(t+1)}=\arctan\left(\frac{2\dfrac{G(t)}{H(t)}}{1-\left(\dfrac{G(t)}{H(t)}\right)^2}\right)=2\arctan\frac{G(t)}{H(t)},$$ which is of the form

$$K(t+1)=2K(t),$$ and has the solution

$$K(t)=2^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\kappa\left(\{ t\}\right)$$ for an arbitrary function $\kappa$ defined on $[0,1)$.

From these results,

$$G(t)=\iota^{2^{\lfloor t\rfloor}}\left(\{ t\}\right)\sin\left(2^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\kappa\left(\{ t\}\right)\right),\\
H(t)=\iota^{2^{\lfloor t\rfloor}}\left(\{ t\}\right)\cos\left(2^{\lfloor t\rfloor}\kappa\left(\{ t\}\right)\right),$$

or

$$g(x)=\iota^{2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}}\left(\{\log_2 x\}\right)\sin\left(2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}\kappa\left(\{\log_2 x\}\right)\right),\\
h(x)=\iota^{2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}}\left(\{\log_2 x\}\right)\cos\left(2^{\lfloor\log_2 x\rfloor}\kappa\left(\{\log_2 x\}\right)\right).$$

Of course with $\iota(t):=1$ and $\kappa(t):=2^t$ you obtain $g(x)=\sin(x),h(x)=\cos(x)$, but there are many other possibilities.